# How do I handle mouse coordinates on mac's SWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swt

Using SWT, if I add a `MouseMoveListener` to a `Table`, the `MouseMove` events I receive come with the mouse coordinates.

On Windows, the coordinates are relative to the visible area.  That is, the top left of the table is always (0,0), regardless of it being scrolled or not.

But on MacOS, the coordinates are relative to the table as a whole.  That is, the top left of the table is (0,0) only if it's not scrolled.

How can I convert MacOS's relative-to-the-table-as-a-whole coordinates to relative-to-the-visible-area coordinates?

Using `Table.toDisplay()` doesn't help.

Comment: I don't see anything looking at the Table source. Why do you care? Things like Table.getItem still work fine.

Comment: Our TableItems "react" when the mouse cursor is over them.  If the user places the mouse over an item, stops moving the mouse and then the item moves to a different place, we have to make it discard its reactions and the new one under the mouse react accordingly.  We do this saving the cursor coordinates.